# Angularjs UI Grid Totals per Row inside the row

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

{{ HelloWorld }}

I'm trying to access the values from other columns in the same row in angular-ui-grid. I have two question that are related.

1. **How can I add the values from several columns in the same row to get a Total?**
2. **How can I use the row index to pass it as a parameter and remove the current row?**

[image]

As you can see in the above image, the Totals that I'm looking for are only related to the integer values and not the initial string.
Also the Button with an X should delete the row when clicked. The rows are included in the grid dynamically.

I've gone through the [UI Grid Tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/) but the examples don't show how to accomplish either of my questions.

My footer is working fine. It's configure to give a total but by column in the entire set of rows:

[image]

Here's a little bit of my code with what I've found so far:

```
var removeTemplate = '<button type="button" class="grid-remove btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="removeRow($event, row.entity)"></span></button>';

$scope.gridAccountableHours = {
    enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
    showColumnFooter: true
};

$scope.gridAccountableHours.columnDefs = [
  { name: "contractCode", displayName: ""},
  { name: "hours1", displayName: "1", type: "number" },
  { name: "hours2", displayName: "2", type: "number", aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum },
  { name: "hours3", displayName: "3", type: "number", aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum },
  { name: "hours4", displayName: "4", type: "number", aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum },
  { name: "hours5", displayName: "5", type: "number", aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum },
  { name: "hours6", displayName: "6", type: "number", aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum },
  { name: "hours7", displayName: "7", type: "number", aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum },
  { name: "hours8", displayName: "8", type: "number", aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum },
  { name: "hours9", displayName: "9", type: "number", aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum },
  { name: "hours10", displayName: "10", type: "number", aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum },
  { name: "hours11", displayName: "11", type: "number", aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum },
  { name: "hours12", displayName: "12", type: "number", aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum },
  { name: "hours13", displayName: "13", type: "number", aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum },
  { name: "hours14", displayName: "14", type: "number", aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum },
  { name: "hours15", displayName: "15", type: "number", aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum },
  { name: "total", displayName: "Total" },
  { name: "remove", displayName: "", cellTemplate: removeTemplate }
];

$scope.removeRow = function ($event, entity) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope.gridAccountableHours.data.splice($scope.gridAccountableHours.data.indexOf(entity), 1);
};
```

I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totalling across the grid you could do with a function on the gridRow.

```
$scope.gridAccountableHours.forEach(function(rowEntity) {
  rowEntity.total = function() {
    var total = 0;
    for( var 1 = 1; i++; i<=15 ){
      total += this['hours'+i];
    }
  };
});
```

Your total column def should automatically bind to this total function.  Refer http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/106_binding

For the delete button, you're missing the appScope, refer http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/305_appScope

Your template ng-click should be:

```
ng-click="grid.appScope.removeRow($event, row.entity)"
```

Comment: Both solutions worked. I did prefer to make the summary individually on each field and it works just fine. Thank you Paul. I hope this helps someone else as well.